# How to get the value of columns to other column when grid is edit/add mode

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, jqgrid

He I got a problem in Grid, i want to do some operation like `column A`,`column B` both are dropdowns having string value, i want to use this `two` values in `column C` to fetch the `data(single value)` from datebase using `Query`. Can You tell Me How to get the `two column values` to `third column` and how to perform operation in third column to fetch data from database using two column values. Please Help me thanks in advance .

**This is my code**

```
  <div class='wrapper' align="center">
    <table id="jqGrid" ></table> 
    <div id="jqGridPager" ></div>   
  </div> 

<script>
        $('#appweek').on('change', function (event) { alert('Applicable Date Changed'); $('#jqGrid').trigger("reloadGrid"); });

        function myelem (value, options) {
          var el = document.createElement("input");
          el.type="text";
          el.value = $("#appweek option:selected" ).text();
          return el;
        }

        function myvalue(elem, operation, value) {
            if(operation === 'get') {
               return $(elem).val();
            } else if(operation === 'set') {
               $('input',elem).val(value);
            }
        }

        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            url:'server.php',
            editurl: 'add.php',
            datatype: "json",
            shrinkToFit: true,
            colNames:['REQUEST NO','Employee_Login','Applicable Date','Change_Type','New_Value','Existing_Value','Requestor NOTES','Status'],
            colModel:[
                {name:'ID', index:'ID',align:"center"},
                {name:'Employee_Login', index:'Employee_Login', align:"center",editable:true,editrules: { required: true},edittype:'select',editoptions:{dataUrl:'el.php'}},
                {name:'applicable_date', index:'applicable_date', align:"center",hidden:true,editable:true,editrules: {required: true},edittype:'custom', editoptions:{readonly: true,custom_element: myelem, custom_value:myvalue}},
                {name:'Change_Type', index:'Change_Type', align:"center",editable:true,editrules: { required: true},edittype:'select', editoptions: { value: "WeekNo:WeekNo; WeekBeginning:WeekBeginning; SITE:SITE; WFH:WFH; ManagerLogin:ManagerLogin; Lead:Lead; CostCenter:CostCenter; Business_Title:Business_Title; Function:Function; WorkGroup:WorkGroup; LoginTime:LoginTime; ROLE:ROLE; SecondarySkill:SecondarySkill; WeekOff:WeekOff;"}},
                {name:'New_Value', index:'New_Value', align:"center",editable:true,editrules: { required: true}},
                {name:'Existing_Value', index:'Existing_Value', align:"center",editable:true,editrules: { required: true},edittype:'select',editoptions:{dataUrl:'ex.php'}},
                {name:'Requestor_NOTES', index:'Requestor_NOTES', align:"center",editable:true,edittype:'textarea', editoptions: {rows:"2",cols:"10"}},
                {name:'Status', index:'Status', align:"center",editable:false},
            ],      
            rowNum:200,
            rowList:[400,300,200],
            pager: '#jqGridPager',
            sortorder: "asc",
            sortname:'id',
            viewrecords: true,
            height:'500',
            width:'1000',

        });

        jQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid('navGrid',"#jqGridPager",{edit:false,del:false,search:false,add:false});
        jQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid('inlineNav',"#jqGridPager");

    </script>
```

Comment: Can you please tell, what you have tried, and your HTML structure?

Comment: It is all about jqgrid..and some ajax call

Comment: Still, can you please give the HTML Structure, so that we can try from here.

Comment: @Samir That is my code ..

Comment: In that code i want to fetch `Existing_Value` automatically from the database , whenever i selected the `Employee_Login` and `Change_Type` from dropdown list.i hope fetching that `Existing_Value` using ajax call or jquery exactly i don't know,

Comment: @Oleg can you help me

Comment: Guys atleast please tell me how to get cell value while editing